# Flutter: Can initialize Firebase dynamic link, remote config, authentication, and deep link in a separate isolate work?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, dart-isolates

My app uses Firestore, Auth, Remoteconfig, Dynamic link, in app Messaging and FCM in the main isolate and Im thinking of moving Auth,Remotecongig,dynamic link , FCM and in app messaging to to a separate isolate.

I currently use the get_it package to lazy load these function's.
For auth I use provider package to listen to auth state change.

My question is will it improve performance and work properly as it does in the main isolae.

Any example or reference will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option would be having a loading screen while app's getting the stuff that is essential for it to work? At least that's how I do it and for Firestore and stuff I have a backend..

I suppose you know how isolates communicate with each other. Main isolate has everything in it so if your tasks are resource hungry (remote config is definitely not, for example) then maybe offloading some of the work into another isolate might be a good idea.
For working with isolates I like this package, mostly under the radar, but it does the job: https://pub.dev/packages/computer

Check it out on Github too, code is pretty straightforward.